# Broken 12V connector on USB cable

Tags: 5vz

Did not see it but someone must have had this problem.  My 12v (cig) connector is BROKEN.  The center terminal came out and is LOST. I want to replace it with another connector (or do I?). .  but unsure of the wiring from the output of the cig connector to the USB cable until I cut it.  I want to be sure I get the 5volts to the correct USB line and dont get it to the other signal lines in the USB line.

Comment: I hate the cigarette lighter as a power adapter, it just needs to die.

Comment: @GaryBak it is a simple device, common and convenient. There are other plug&socket systems that are relevant, but getting agreement by every manufacturer and all the device manufacturers may be challenging.

Comment: You have a hot, exposed 12VDC line that was fused high enough to power a cig lighter lost somewhere behind the dash and **that isn't your most immediate problem**?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the OP talks about the adapter tip and not about the socked in the dashboard being broken.

Answer (score 1):

The centre tip of the cigar lighter is positive, so would be connected to the red wire.

But, and it is a big but, cheap cables may not have red / black as pos & neg...

So, be sure and check with a multimeter what goes where.

From what I have seen the outer cables are power, inner pair data...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the power outlet of your car. If so then you can get to buy the power outlet socket. It is easy to fix with just one connector.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multimeter you would be able to check the polarity of the cigarette lighter before reconnecting USB devices.